# Can't connect MySQL on server

Tags: php, mysql, database

If I try to connect to my MySQL database on my server(hosted on GoDaddy), I get this error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request. Please contact the server
>   administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything
>   you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

I don't know how to get the server error log.

But if I try to connect to the database remotely(on my pc), It works fine.

I use this code:

```
<?php
class MY_SQL{
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $conn;

    public function __construct($SERVERNAME){
        $this->username = "username";
        $this->password = "password";

        if($SERVERNAME == "data_"){
            $server = "server_ip";
        }
        else {
            $server = $SERVERNAME;
        }

        // Create connection
        $this->conn = new mysqli($server, $this->username, $this->password, "data_");

        // Check connection
        if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $this->conn->connect_error);
        } 
    }
 }

 //connect to database
 $database = new MY_SQL("data_");
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: How are we supposed to know what's wrong? We can't access the server log.

Comment: Does it fail when you are using the `ip address` or the SERVERNAME or both?

Comment: I understand, but I don't know how to get acces to it.

Comment: @float, Is your website on Dedicated Server or on Shared Hosting ? If it's on dedicated server you may be able to get access on MySQL logs

Comment: @LuFFy Shared Hosting

Comment: @float, As You are on shared Hosting, You won't be able to get mysql Logs.... Now Try Connecting server using your local machine using `"mysql -h[IP_ADDRESS] -p[PASSWORD]"`

Comment: @LuFFy It works fine on my local machine

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I had a deconstructor in my class which caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mysqli becouse it's old use pdo.Also don't put everything in one file.....
Here is a working code,i have organized it into folders.

```
index.php
scripts/
       dbcon/
            dbconfig.php
       functions
            start.php
            functions.php
       funcs.php
```

**dbconfig.php**

```
<?php
class Database{
  private $host = 'localhost';
  private $db_name = '';
  private $username = 'root';
  private $pass = 'root';
  public $conn;

  public function dbConnection(){
    $this -> conn = null;
    try{
      $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->db_name,$this->username,$this->pass);
      $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
      echo "Connection error:".$e->getMessage();
    }
    return $this->conn;
  }
}
?>
```

**start.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','On');
define('APP_ROOT',__DIR__);
define('ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

require_once ROOT."/scripts/dbcon/dbconfig.php";
session_start();

?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'start.php';

class ADMIN{
  private $conn;

  public function __construct(){
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->dbConnection();
    $this->conn = $db;
  }

  your functions

}
```

**funcs.php**

```
<?php
//Imports
require_once 'functions/functions.php';
//Classes
$functions = new ADMIN();

call your functions here from the functions.php
```

?>

Also don't use php as the main page ,create json in php and use polymer or node js o handle the json.
:D